# 音声認識アプリを作りたい

Tags: c++

例えば、下記のようなアプリを作りたいと思っています。

1. アプリを起動
2. 「あ」という画像をPCモニターに出力する。
3. モニターに出力された文字をみた人が、「あ」とむかって、マイクに言う。
4. 書いてる文字と、人の声が一致しているかの正答をアプリが判断。
5. 正解していれば画像に赤丸をつける。不正なら×。
6. 正解不正解問わず、次の文字「い」を画面に表示。
7. 3から5の繰り返し。

というアプリを作りたいと思っています。できれば、「あ」「い」「う」「え」「お」と順番に出すのではなくランダム要素も含めたいのです。

Windows環境でまずはやってみたいと思います。その次に、Androidでも動作させたいと思います。

どのような言語やライブラリを用いれば上記のようなアプリを作成することが可能でしょうか？可能であれば、ナレッジとかAPIの説明がのっているサイトも教えていただければ助かります。

ご教示のほうよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 具体的に動作フローを考えていらっしゃるようでなによりですが、恐らくこのような形の質問ですと回答がつきづらいかと思われます。基本的に分からないことに対して質問と回答の形になるので質問者さんの分からないこと教えて欲しいことをもう少し細分化し具体的に記載するとよろしいかと思います。現状ですと何処から何を伝えればいいのか分からないので、究極に悪い言い方をすると「私の変わりにこのプログラムを組んで見せてください」という質問になってしまいます。

Comment: どこまでプログラムを作りましたか？　何に（どこに）難しいところがあるのですか？　何が判れば満足ですか？？？　プログラムの経験やスキルについての情報があると、回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: Siegsさん　Fumu 7さん　ご意見ありがとうございます。どの言語ではその開発はできない。とか知りたかっただけなんです。普通にインプットアウトプットぐらいならやったことはあるのですが、音声認識という機能を追加するとなると、開発できない言語とかあるのかな？っとおもったのです。または、開発しやすい言語とかをしれればいいな。と思ったのです。

Comment: 間違いなく音声認識部分が肝になると思います。精度が悪ければ利用者はどんなに努力しても認識されないわけですから。その点も踏まえて質問者さんはどのように実現するお考えでしょうか？ この部分だけは第三者に任せることができないかと。

Answer (score 4):

残念ながら、音声認識のプログラムを何の知識もないところから自分で開発するのは無理です。

でも、音声認識をする機能を提供してくれているところがあるので、そういうものを使えば
「書いてる文字と、人の声が一致しているかの正答をアプリが判断」というのを実現できる可能性があります。

それは、Google社が提供している"Cloud Speech-to-Text API "というサービスです。

どんなことができるかは、[Googleの音声認識エンジンを使って音声ファイルから文字起こししてみた](https://gigazine.net/news/20180824-speech-to-text-gcp-cloud-mojiokoshi/)　の記事などを見てください。

"Google speach-to-text"で検索すると、いろいろな情報が得られると思います。

> ３．モニターに出力された文字をみた人が、「あ」とむかって、マイクに言う。
>   ４．書いてる文字と、人の声が一致しているかの正答をアプリが判断。

３．の"「あ」とむかって、マイクに言う。"のところは、
・マイクの音声を録音する(WAV等のspeach-to-textの入力に使える形式のデータにして保存する）。

４．の”書いてる文字と、人の声が一致しているかの正答をアプリが判断”は、
・録音した音声のデータを、speach-to-textを使って、文章に変換する。
　モニタに出力した文字と、speach-to-textの変換結果を比較して、一致してれば正答と判断するのは、そんなに難しくないと思います

簡単にとはいかないと思いますが、最も難しい”音を文字に変換する”部分を自分で作らなくて済むので、望むようなアプリを作れると思いますよ。

頑張ってください！